# How to reproduce the behavior of an app expecting node_modules to be served with webjars

Tags: webjars

A front-end developer would run `npm install` to generate the `node_modules` directory and then serve the root of his project with a simple HTTP server. This allows him to refer any asset in a URL starting with `node_modules/...`.

I'm looking for a solution where I can serve the application statics in a servlet 3 container deploying all the front-end dependencies under the form of NPM webjars dropped in the classpath.

My issue is that URLs starting with `node_modules` won't be resolved because WebJars assets are exposed under `webjars`. Is there any recommended way to keep URLs starting node_moules valid?

I would simply write a servlet filter that redirects `node_modules` to `webjars`. What do you think?

Comment: What container are you using?

Comment: It can be any servlet 3 container

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a [class](https://github.com/wuic/wuic-extensions/blob/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/webjars/src/main/java/com/github/wuic/webjars/NpmWebJarTranslator.java) that detects all available `WebJars` thanks to the `WebJarAssetLocator` and compute for each asset the corresponding `node_modules` URL. The class takes care of any existing `package.json` that is available in any `NPM WebJar` to add the module name to the translated URL instead of artifact ID.
Then it's possible to write a [filter](https://github.com/wuic/wuic-extensions/blob/wuic-0.5.x-snapshot/webjars/src/main/java/com/github/wuic/webjars/NpmWebJarFilter.java#L88) with url mapping `/node_modules/*` to redirect requests to the corresponding WebJar URL.